# Perl: How to test if any value (even zero) has been assigned to a hash key

Tags: perl, hash

Is there a correct way of testing if a particular hash key has already been assigned any value, even if this value is zero? I have been working with a statement like this:

```
%hash=();
$hash{a}=1;
$hash{b}=0;
if($hash{$key}) { do something }
```

but this gives the same result for keys that have neven been touched and those that have been assigned the value 0 (e.g. both $hash{b} and $hash{c} evaluate as 'false'). Is there a way of telling the difference between those two ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) operator to check if something has value which is not `undef`

```
if ( defined $hash{ $key } ) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Use the [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) operator to check if a `$key` of a `%hash` has been written to

```
if ( exists $hash{ $key } ) {
  //do stuff
}
```

The difference being that `defined` checks to see if a value is of anything other than `undef` and `exists` is used to verify if `$key` is a key of the hash despite its value.

Comment: Thanks for this solution,  Most helpful!

Comment: I wouldn't say "EVER"; if you delete it, it no longer exists.  exists tests that there is a value, whether or not it is defined.

Comment: Note: If you use defined() on a key that does not yet exist, it will be called into existence. This may be an undesirable side effect.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, That's wrong. If I do `$hash{ $key } = undef;`, `defined $hash{ $key }` returns false even though I gave it a value.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, That's not true. `defined` NEVER creates keys. You're probably talking about `defined($h{k1}->{k2})`, where `->` creates hash, a reference to that hash, and assigns to `$h{k1}`.

Comment: @ikegami - giving it a value of undef is not giving it a value. It not longer has a defined value, it's undef.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, I didn't say it was a *defined* value, I said it was *a* value. I write code that assigns undef and returns undef daily. If undef is not a value, then you're saying I'm doing that for nothing, and that's clearly wrong. You even specifically said it checks for false values, yet it doesn't.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, `defined`'s documentation says it checks if the *value* passed to it is defined. If undef isn't a value, `defined` would always return true.

Comment: @ikegami - it checks a code block. But I've cleaned up my descriptions.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, What checks a code block for what? `defined` checks the *value* returned by an *expression*. What cleanup? The sentence is still there.

Comment: @ikegami - As compared to exists $h{k1}->{k2} which does not autovivify the hash keys.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, Sorry, but that's wrong too. The `->` in `exists $h{k1}->{k2}` will autovivify `$h{k1}`. `$h{k1}->{k2}` is the same thing as `( $h{k1} //= {} )->{k2}` whether it's the arg of `defined`, `exists` or something else.

Answer (score 5):

See [`perldoc -f defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) and [`perldoc -f exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html):

```
my %hash = (foo => 0, bar => undef);

print defined $hash{foo}; # true
print defined $hash{bar}; # false
print exists $hash{bar};  # true
print exists $hash{baz};  # false

delete $hash{bar};
print exists $hash{bar};  # false
```

Comment: "exists" is for Key. "defined" is for Value.

Comment: @aartist: I have no idea what you mean; can you explain?

Comment: zoul: if you are going to use say in an example, you really should include a `use 5.010;` or something else to make it runnable; also, those aren't perl comments

Comment: That script isn't going to produce useful output; it won't actually print "true" or "false".  `defined` and `exists` return 1 for true, the empty string for false.  But it does make the point, and something like `print defined $hash{foo} ? "Yes\n" : "No\n"` might be too verbose.

Comment: @aartist: `exists $hash{foo}` tells you whether `'foo'` is a *key* in `%hash`, regardless of the associated value.  `defined $hash{foo}` is a test on the *value* (and, for convenience, it returns false rather than blowing up if `$hash{foo}` doesn't exist`).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `defined()` to check if the key actually exists in the hash:

```
if (defined($hash{$key})) { do('something'); };
```

Comment: I presume `do('something');` wasn't meant to be literal (it actually uses "something" as a file name and executes that file's contents as Perl).

Comment: You absolutely can NOT use defined() to check if a key exists in a hash. You can use defined to test if the value associated with a key is defined or not. You use exists() to check if a key exists in a hash.